# 2 Urls for the same target page after changing the location

Tags: javascript, url

I don't understand something. Suppose I go to `https://example.com` and it's showing me a default location ("Hilden") and it has a way to let me change that default location to "Langenfeld." But after I do that, the URL changes to `https://langenfeld.example.com/?change=5`. I just want it to be `https://langenfeld.example.com/`. How do I get rid of the part after the last `/`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you're asking. Are you in control of the site described? If so, what exactly don't you understand about the query string and subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well instead of passing the href of the target field as

```
<a href="https://langenfeld.example.com?change=5" target="_self" rel="nofollow">
Langenfeld
</a>
```

you may use:

```
<a href="https://langenfeld.example.com" target="_self" rel="nofollow">
Langenfeld
</a>
```